# Angular 2 Conditional Display

Tags: angular

I have a function, `loggedIn()`, that returns a function built in to `angular2-jwt` called `tokenNotExpired()`. If `tokenNotExpired()` returns true, the person is logged in (has a JWT assigned to them) and certain parts of my app are shown hidden based on this. On page load, the page shows the elements correctly. If I'm logged in and then logout, the parts of the page are hidden that should be, but if I am logged out and then log in, nothing changes until a hard refresh.

It seems like if it works one way, it should work the other way too. Am I missing something? Is there something with change detection that I'm missing? I'll put my code below, but it's pretty basic stuff.

#### session.ts

```
import {tokenNotExpired} from 'angular2-jwt';
loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
}
```

#### app.ts

```
loggedIn() {
    return this._session.loggedIn();
}
```

Then in the template I have `*ngIf="loggedIn()"` or `*ngIf="!loggedIn()"` on the parts that I want to show/hide, respectively. I've also tried `*ngIf="loggedIn() == true"` or `*ngIf="loggedIn() == false"`, just in case.

## ******Edit*******

Just as an extra part of the code, I thought this might help:

```
login() {
    this.lock.show((error: string, profile: Object, id_token: string) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token);
        this._router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
    });
}
```

That's the login function, using Auth0 and their lock widget to login.

Comment: This is not enough information to debug your problem. Can you try to make it reproducible in a Plunker (template https://plnkr.co/edit/XzG7CG?p=info)

Comment: I tried to make a plunk with it, but can't get the same setup because I think it has something to do with the isLoggedIn() function not being called after logging in with Auth0. [This is the article I used for reference](https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-authentication) and I did everything that he does here. That'll give you more of a code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what to do to fix the issue. In my case at least, I needed to use `NgZone` and call the `run` function after logging in. From what I understand, the login was happening without the components knowing about it. using `NgZone.run()` re-rendered the components and the values were all updated appropriately.

This may not work in all situations, but it did work in this case.